# Regex : ignore if there is an html tag

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I have a regex pattern:

```
\(\s*\'\s*(.*?)\s*\'\)
```

This pattern means, get any text between ('TEXT').

There is a problem: The text may have a HTML tags.

So I want a pattern. If it didn't find a HTML tags, get the text normally, but if it found a HTML tags, the pattern get the text between the tags.

---

Example:

If the text is

> `('foo foo text here')`

the pattern gets:

> foo foo text here

---

And if the text is:

> `('<div class='test'> foo foo text here </div>')`

the pattern gets

> foo foo text here

So the pattern ignore the HTML tags (if there is any), and grab the text .

Comment: I need a button that just does this for me. DON'T REGEX HTML, PARSE IT!

Comment: As usual: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: This isn't an HTML parsing question. It's an HTML stripping question disguised as an HTML parsing question.

Comment: Tricky, tricky. You're right. I still like excuses to use that link, though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.strip-tags.php) inside your `preg_match()`.  That will turn:

```
('<div class='test'> foo foo text here </div>')
```

Into:

```
( 'foo foo text here' )
```

Then your regex as you designed it will remove the parens.

```
preg_match("/\(\s*\'\s*(.*?)\s*\'\)/", strip_tags($yourstring), $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works as well:

```
>\s*(.*?)\s*</|\(\s*\'(?!<)\s*(.*?)\s*\'\)
```

Although it does capture to two different capture groups.

At least it might be another option :-)